# Collapsing `margin` on `<legend>` tag

Tags: css

Can someone see why `margin-bottom` on the legend tag is collapsing? Thanks. I wouldn't normally post stupid CSS bugs like this, but this ones an exception :P

http://jsfiddle.net/pickledegg/XtR53/2/

Comment: The problem seems to only appear in webkit browsers and to be caused by the default behavior of the "fieldset" element. If you replace it with div, the margin works fine. Try resetting the CSS for fieldset.

Comment: Yes thanks, I just noticed it was Chrome-only. Thumbs up!

Comment: Actually, it seems to affect all webkit-based browsers (at lest the ones I've got)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
legend+label {
    margin-top:50px;
    -webkit-margin-top-collapse: separate;
}
```

And you'd need to remove the `margin-bottom` from the `legend`.

I think this is a known WebKit bug.

Here's a modified Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yRQDW/1/

Comment: The thing is, you're getting a double margin in other browsers.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to remove the bottom margin from the legend! I have amended my Fiddle, and updated the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-bottom:50px;` in `legend` CSS.

Comment: I think the problem is that the margin is NOT showing in webkit browsers.